# What is the difference between "rb+" and "wb+"?

Tags: python, file

`rb+` and `wb+` both read from and write to a binary file, so what makes them different?

Is it the order they read and write?

Comment: Do you mean apart from the fact that opening in read only denies being able to write?

Comment: @JonClements Neither of these are read-only, `+` means "open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)".

Comment: @user4815162342 ahh... yes... of course... that's quite an embarrassing brain burp of mine :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short

- `rb+` does not create the file from scratch
- `wb+` does create the file from scratch

there are no differences aside that.

Comment: It's important to realize that "create the file from scratch" implies "destroy (truncate to length 0) existing one, if found".

Comment: Oh so with `rb+` the file must already exist?

Comment: @coder80 Indeed file must already exist while using `rb+`.

Comment: @coder80 Yes. Sadly, there is no mode for "use the file if it exists, create one if not". (Other than `r` and `w`, there is also `x` which is like the opposite of `r`, in that it will create the file if it doesn't exist, but it will *fail* if it exists.)

Comment: One would think ab+ should do that, but it does not